# How do I pull from two data sources for one UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to know how to implement a search bar that functions much like the one on the Instagram app. My search bar is placed above a UITableView (friends list). Currently it filters the friends list to match the search term. My goal is to also have the search bar pull data from my server (Parse) and display that below the locally searched data.

IE: 
Searching "Steve" would return a UITableView of all the local Steve's in the user's friends list and other Steve's that are on the server but the user is not friends with. Then the user could tap that person and send them a friend request.

How would I go about achieving this feature?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a view controller (preferably a    `UITableViewController`) that conforms to `UISearchBarDelegate`,    `UITableViewDataSource`, and `UITableViewDelegate`.

Once those protocol methods are set up properly, you can switch    between two dataSources, 
e.g., an `NSArray` for `users` and an    `NSMutableArray` for `searchResults`.

Then, in the `UISearchBarDelegate` methods, you can update the    `searchResults` mutable array with the results of the search text    predicate and refresh the `tableView` data.

If the search is cancelled or cleared out, the `searchResults` should    return `nil`.

In the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, check whether `searchResults`    exists, and if so, load your cells from that array:

```
@interface YourViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
/* ... */

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *users;

@end

@implementation YourViewControler

/* ... */

- (void)setSearchResults:(NSMutableArray *)searchResults
{
    _searchResults = searchResults;
    [self.mainView.collectionView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.searchResults) {
        return self.searchResults.count;
    } else {
        return users.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (self.searchResults) {
        /* ...  */
    } else {
        /* ... */
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length > 2) {
        NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(user.name CONTAINS[cd] %@) OR (user.username CONTAINS[cd] %@)", searchText, searchText];
        self.searchResults = [[self.users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate] mutableCopy];
        NSLog(@"Search Result: %@", [self.searchResults valueForKey:@"username"]);
    } else if (searchText.length == 0) {
        self.searchResults = nil;
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    self.searchResults = nil;
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```